# How are filters able to pass frequencies correctly when multiple signals are present?

Tags: signal, capacitance, signal-theory

I have absolutely no experience in the world of EE but I'm self studying and I have some questions on how filtering works when multiple signals are involved.

I understand the graphs of filters showing how much of the signal is allowed to pass when only a single frequency is present, but I can't understand how filtering can work if there's multiple signals involved.

For example I've been playing around with the graph of $$sin(x)+sin(1.4x)$$ Let's say for instance I have a perfect low pass filter that will allow $$sin(x)$$ to pass, but completely block $$sin(1.4x)$$ If we take these values to be voltages, at $$x=\frac{5\pi}{2}, sin(x)=1$$ but $$sin(x)+sin(1.4x) = 0$$

If the signal were to pass through as I would expect, how is it possible for output voltage of the at time \$\frac{5\pi}{2}\$ be 1, when the total voltage at the input at time \$\frac{5\pi}{2}\$ is 0? I understand that there's some phase shift that's related to how much of the signal is allowed to pass, but in this example \$sin(x)\$ was allowed to pass through completely, so there shouldn't be any phase shift?

Comment: What you didn't show is sin(1.4x) = -1, where x = 5pi/2. So, the unfiltered version would input and pass sin(x)+sin(1.4x) = +1-1 =0. If you, instead, use a filter to pass this signal and it (ideally) completely removes the tone at sin(1.4x) then you no longer have the -1 contribution passing though, leaving you with only the value of +1 or the sin(x) tone. You aren't really passing 0 through the filter but two separate tones that when combined equal 0 at the frequency of 5pi/2. Remove one tone then the combination is different.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now!

Comment: The filter is actually looking at the rate of change. It doesn't know if what is passing through it is a sinudsoid or not because that would require knowing the future (mathematically, a true sinusoid exists since the beginning of time and continues to exist for all time). As humans we compartmentalize this as frequency.

Comment: @DKNguyen But most filters have delay, and thus _do_ "know the future" from the reference frame of the output signal.

Answer (score 4):

No matter how simple or how complex a signal waveform is, an any instant in time there is only one voltage.  The signal can be a pure sine wave from a test generator, or the audio waveform of a symphony orchestra.  Doesn't matter; at any instant, only one voltage.

Therefore, you cannot think about combining or filtering signals in terms of specific voltages at specific moments in time.  A filter does not react to voltage instants.  It reacts to the frequency characteristics of continuous waveforms.

When you mix two sine waves as you describe, of course there will be instants when the algebraic sum of the two waveforms is zero volts.  There will be other times when the sum is the positive peak of the combined wave, and other times when it is the negative peak.  None of these values are anything near a complete statement about the nature of the signal.

Filters have reactive elements, and by definition these elements store and release energy over time.  Thus a filter affects only the changing nature of the signal; you cannot high-pass or low-pass filter pure DC.

Comment: "*It reacts to the frequency characteristics of continuous waveforms.*" You might just want to say rate of change here.

Comment: Everything in the op suggests he is describing the transient values of two perfect infinite sine waves at two frequencies and equal amplitudes (and the signal comprised of their summation) at a specific point in time. These values can be extracted, combined, and summed at a specific instant in time, pre and post filter. Unless I misunderstood your post, it sounds like you are saying this is not possible. The value of 0 he described is not DC, it is the value of the composite signal at that instant in time.

Comment: You misunderstood, or I was not clear enough.  I'm not saying it isn't possible, I'm saying that is not the correct way to view how a filter interacts with (affects) the signals going through it.  In a way (this is gonna come back and bite me), it is a philosophical thing.  When does a series of dots become a line?  To understand how a filter works, see the line, not the dots.

Comment: @AnalogKid. Thanks. I think I understand your point. I tried to make my commentary a little more clear in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No filter "completely" blocks anything. It simply attenuates the signal.  There are many, many, many places to the right of the decimal point before you reach zero.

Next, filters attenuate all signals some amount. Note the similarity to above - there are many, many place holders for 9s to the right of the decimal point before you reach 1.0!

To discriminate between two signals, the filter (for simplicity think a resistor and a capacitor as a low-pass configuration).
A fast moving signal (high frequency) isn't providing a high positive voltage for a long enough duration to pass current through the resistor and charge a capacitor before the source signal goes low and doesn't have much time to discharge a capacitor (through the resistor). The signal on the capacitor is attenuated significantly vs the slower oscillation speed signal - which has more time to charge and discharge the capacitor (and pass the signal along to the target in the next stage of the circuit).
So, the filer is not looking to discriminate and separate the two signals, it is just a function of how much time and potential (voltage) difference is available to charge and discharge the capacitor (when the current is limited by the resistor).

Reversing the cap and resistor to make a high pass filter, think about it the same way - how much time is available and to charge or discharge the cap (slow signal and fast signal).

Or, think about slow changing time-slice in your complex function and fast changing time slice in your complex function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to expand on my comments here.

First, let's establish that fourier analysis allows us to decompose any periodic series into a summation of a set of weighted sine and cosine series. This is why DFT and FFT algorithms are extremely useful in signal processing and analysis. A consequence of this is that we can extract all of the properties of the individual series, with only the knowledge of the composite series!

Now, let's start by assuming that we have two signals at two different frequencies,
\$s_1 = sin(x)\$ and \$s_2 = sin(1.4x)\$ we can combine or sum these signals to get a third composite signal we will call \$s_3\$, where \$s_3 = s_1 + s_2\$. We can plot these signals on a graph to more clearly see the signals.
[image]
Now, we can look at any instant in time and evaluate the amplitudes of the signals. Take, \$t= \frac{5pi}{2}\$, and we see \$s_1 = 1\$ and \$s_2 = -1\$ at that instant.
Notice that the sum of the individual signal amplitudes at that point in time will give us the amplitude (not to be confused with DC value) of the composite signal, \$s_3\$ at the same instant in time.

Now, the op looked at that \$s_3\$ amplitude of \$0\$ at that single point in time and wondered, how can a gainless passive filter receive that value as input and pass a value of 1 at the output, given the same time instant?

Let's assume we have an ideal brick wall filter (no phase delay or real impairments here).  A filter will look at the entire spectrum of all the components of the fourier decomposition of a composite signal, and selectively pass some and remove (strongly attenuate) others.  In our case, we only have two signals of significance, where all other signals have weights of zero. We can assume that our filter perfectly passed the first signal \$s_1\$ and removed the second \$s_2\$. If this is the case, then the output filtered composite signal will just be \$s_1\$. And we know the instantaneous amplitude of that signal at\$\frac{5pi}{2}\$ is just 1.

The scenario can be built in a simulator or breadboard as well, to confirm. But practically, the filter will create some delay between signals, and other imperfections. It's best to build a crude low pass filter, with two very widely spaced signals to see this.